# How do you get Internet Free/Busy to publish in Outlook 2013?

Tags: outlook, office-2013

Our company has a shared network drive folder for everyone's Free/Busy .vfb files.  I confirmed I have permissions to read/write to this folder.

I followed the directions to configure Outlook 2013 (32-bit version, running off Windows 7 x64) from [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291621).  I can see other people's Free/Busy information, but nobody can see mine.  Outlook never publishes my .vfb file to the folder.  Other employees with Outlook 2007 and 2010 don't have this issue.

Another person posted this problem that's very close to mine on [another forum](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1336694-Outlook-2013-Free-Busy-issue) and I've tried the same troubleshooting steps.  I'm experiencing the same "71 months" issue he's having as well.  I've tried disabling the firewall and [verified registry settings](http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/89598-free-busy-supposed-work-outlook-2013-not-connected-exchange/index2), but nothing is working.  I even tried adding an older Outlook "UseLegacyFB" DWORD value but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Outlook 2013. See this : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/d265a5c6-9f99-410a-8862-a374de1b4144/freebusy-not-publishing-with-outlook-2013-without-exchange

> This issue has been submitted to the Outlook Team for a fix but we do not have an estimated
>   release date yet.  Once I get more information I will post back and update.  When using POP
>   accounts the *.vfb file does not get created properly.